# How to capture network stream as image in Python?

Tags: python, image, network-programming

In VLC I can do "`Media -> Open Network Stream`" and under "`Please enter a network URL`" I can put `udp://@239.129.8.16:1234`.
And this is opening local UDP video stream.
VLC is not related to my question, I have put it just for clarification.

How can I connect to `"udp://@239.129.8.16:1234"` network stream in Python, get image from it (screenshot) and save it in file?

Answer (score 0):

I think neither network programming nor Python is the focus of your question here. At the core, you need to feed a video decoder with the binary data stream, make the video decoder collect a sufficient amount of data for decoding a single frame, let the decoder save this, and abort the operation.

I am quite sure that the command line tool [avconv](https://libav.org/avconv.html) from the libav project can do everything you need. All you need to do is dig into the rather complex documentation and find the right command line parameters for your application scenario. From a quick glance, it looks you will need for instance

```
‘-vframes number (output)’

    Set the number of video frames to record. This is an alias for -frames:v.
```

Also, you should definitely search [the docs](https://libav.org/avconv.html) for this sentence:

> If you want to extract just a limited number of frames, you can use
>   the above command in combination with the -vframes or -t option

It also looks like `avconv` can *directly* [read from a UDP stream](https://libav.org/avconv.html#toc-udp).

Note that VLC, the example you gave, uses libav at the core. Also note that if you really need to execute all this "from Python", then spawn `avconv` from within Python using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: I am hoping that Python have batteries included for this one :-)

Comment: Will never happen. You will unlikely get an answer not referring to libav/ffmpeg. Media stream handling is an incredibly complex topic. That is why the community focuses on just a few implementations that are then used by almost everybody. That is, these implementations are usually well-tested and feature-rich. I seriously recommend direct usage of `avconv`, but you can also use libav Python bindings such as https://github.com/mikeboers/PyAV -- but please note that in both cases you have the same amount of work: figuring out the *exact* requirements to configure libav for your use case.